# SQLAlchemy/Flask queries for multiple table and filter

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

With an Python/Flask app, so far I have used simple queries like

```
     SupportedConfig.query.filter_by(tid=int(form.courses.data)).first()
```

to retrieve specific from tables. Now I'm not sure how to convert following
query which involves multiple tables as an SQLAlchemy statment.

```
   select s.sid,d.distroname,t.topicname from SupportedConfig s, distro d, topic t  
   where s.tid = t.tid and s.did = d.did;
```

schema :

```
    suppportconfig : int,int,int #sid,tid,did
    distro  : int,string  #did,distroname
    topic  : int,string   #tid,topicname
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I need to change model and add Foreign-key value.
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html

and then use with

```
 supported_config1 = SupportedConfig.query.filter_by(did=distrodb.did,tid=topic.tid).join(distrodb).join(topic).all ()
```

to get the required python list.

Source : sqlalchemy irc list